# VTK example .exe Stopped Working on Windows 7

Tags: vtk

I managed to compile VTK example (http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/Curvatures) in MSVS 2010 but when I tried to run it, it stopped. Does anyone know the cause? I can run other VTK examples successfully but not this one. [image]

Comment: Did you compile VTK with Visual Studio 2010? Did you build shared libraries? If you built shared libraries did you install VTK? If you installed VTK are you running the configuration you installed? I mean if you install Release VTK that means you can not safely use the Debug configuration with your application.

Comment: You're right! It's working if I built the application in Release configuration. I actually used CMAKE to configure VTK and build shared libraries, then compile it in Release version in Visual Studio 2010. So I guess the application needs the shared libraries of VTK in Release version to run. Thank you for pointing me to the solution!

Comment: To be honest I was bit by this same problem long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the problem is caused by using Release .dlls in a Debug application. Remember that the  Release heap is not compatible to the Debug heap. Which means any allocations in the Release heap can not be freed in the Debug heap or vise versa. As a result of this it is not generally safe to mix Debug and Release in the same application.

Now in the case of VTK (since I have used this on many machines and have built this 100s of times using Visual Studio over the last 5+ years) my recommendations are to turn off the building of shared libraries with vtk. And avoid the use the INSTALL target with for VTK, ITK, GDCM or any CMake based library that names its release libraries the same as its debug libraries. Instead use BUILD_ALL for all configurations you will need in your application. Then when you need to configure your application to use CMake I point VTK_DIR to the root directory of the folder where I built VTK and CMake will then correctly use the Debug libraries in my Debug application, Release libraries in my Release application..